# Linq Multi Join with Where clause

Tags: sql, linq, where-clause

I am trying to use a multi join with a Where clause.

**SQL code has the following working**

```
SELECT... 
FROM clients as c
JOIN members as m ON
(
    c.Id = m.clientId AND 
    c.groupId = m.groupId AND 
    c.created < m.created
)
```

**LINQ code - I dont know where to please the 'Where' clause**

```
from c in clients
join m in members ON
{ClientId = c.Id,GroupId = c.groupId} equals
{ClientId = m.clientId, GroupId = m.groupId}
```

** (c.created < m.created) missing **

where do I put the c.created Where Clause

Comment: Do  you mean you don't know where to place the "Where" clause?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have non-`equals` join conditions in LINQ. You can use additional `WHERE` clause to get equivalent results:

```
from c in clients
join m in members on
new {ClientId = c.Id,GroupId = c.groupId}
equals new {ClientId = m.clientId, GroupId = m.groupId}
where c.created < m.created
```